# GUI automation using pywinauto python. Attribute error , menu_select() missing error in uaicontrols.py

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm tring to automate a windows gui mouse click of a check box in properties of a printer.
 [image: I get to this by starting print management mmc right clicking on "G23XnQ2E (local)" from "Print Servers" drop down in the left pane and selecting properties, switching to "security tab" and i finally want to select the checkbox against manage printer option "]

I get to this by starting print management mmc, right clicking on "G23XnQ2E (local)" from "Print Servers" drop down in the left pane and selecting properties, switching to "security tab" and i finally want to select the checkbox against manage printer option. This can also be achieved by directly clicking on the action menu and selecting properties, provided that i have selected "G23XnQ2E (local)" from the printer servers.

I have tried all the possible ways that I can thing of but always end up getting the many errors like "raise AttributeError", "menu_select", "select()", "click()" - "missing".

my code is like say:

```
from pywinauto import Application

Application().start(r'mmc printmanagement.msc') 
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe')
app.PrintManagement.dump_tree() 
app.dialog.pane1.pane5.pane6.menu.menu_select("Action -> Properties")
#app.dialog.menu_select("Action -> Properties")
#app.dialog.pane1.pane5.pane6.menu.ActionMentuitem.select()
#app.dialog.pane1.pane5.pane6.menu.ActionMentuitem.click()
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov i have been trying solve this from past week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menu_select` is good for main menu like "File->Open". It doesn't work for popup/context menus. This is my code working on my PC (name of print server has been changed to yours):

```
from pywinauto import Application

Application().start(r'mmc printmanagement.msc') 
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe')
#app.PrintManagement.dump_tree()

print_servers = app.PrintManagement.child_window(title="Print Servers", control_type="TreeItem")
print_servers.select() # it expands the subtree

# call popup menu
print_servers.child_window(title="G23XZNQ2E (local)", control_type="TreeItem").right_click_input()

# alternative way to call popup menu
#print_servers.child_window(title_re=".*\(local\)$", control_type="TreeItem").right_click_input()

# select "Properties..." menu item
app.ContextMenu.child_window(title="Properties...", control_type="MenuItem").select()

#app.PrintManagement.Print_Server_Properties.dump_tree()
app.PrintManagement.Print_Server_Properties.TabControl.select('Security')
app.PrintManagement.Print_Server_Properties.child_window(title="Allow Manage Printers", control_type="CheckBox").toggle()
```

All `child_window` specifications have been copied from `dump_tree()` outputs. Some windows are children of main window, but context menu is a top level one. This is not a documented experience, but we're working on a recorder feature planned this year as Beta. So it will be much easier to generate a script without thinking about hierarchy structure so much.

Comment: File "step32.py", line 11, in <module>
    print_servers.child_window(title="G23XNQ2E(local)", control_type="TreeItem").right_click_input()
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 352, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)

Comment: File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 249, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 431, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 210, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'G23XNQ2E(local)', 'control_type': 'TreeItem', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Print Servers', , None>, 'backend': 'uia'}

Comment: any comments on the error in my system. Is it system dependent ?

Comment: the code opens the first Dialog and waits for some time to give the above error.

Comment: Sorry, I have mistyped the title from the screenshot (I have another hostname on my local PC, of course). Now added missed letter `Z` into the title and edited the answer. Please re-check.

Comment: Also added one more commented line as alternative way with `title_re` (didn't check it yet).